# AutoCompleteTextView - programatically set value and close softkeyboard

Tags: android

I'm really struggling with this, so I turn to you good people :)

Goal: during OnCreate set a value in the AutoCompleteTextView and close the keyboard.

Activity: contains 2 views, the AutoCompleteTextView and a Button

In OnCreate I call this;

```
private void SoftKeyboardClose()
{
    IBinder windowToken;
    AutoCompleteTextView actv = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.ac_city);
    Button myBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_search);

    windowToken = myBtn.getWindowToken();

    if (windowToken == null)
    {
        windowToken = this.getWindow().getDecorView().getWindowToken();
    }

    if (windowToken == null)
    {
        windowToken = findViewById(R.id.ac_city).getWindowToken();
    }

    if (windowToken == null)
    {
        windowToken = new View(this).getWindowToken();
    }


    // close it
    InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

    if (inputManager == null)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "inputmanage is null");
    } else if (windowToken == null)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "getWindowToken is null");
    } else
    {
        inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(windowToken, 0);
    }

    myBtn.requestFocus();
    if (myBtn.hasFocus())
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "success - btn has focus");
    } else
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "fail - btn doesn't have focus");
    }
}
```

getWindowToken always returns null.

In response to hpedrorodrigues I tried this;

```
public class ZZZActivity extends Activity
{
private static final String[] COUNTRIES = new String[]{"Belgium", "France", "Italy", "Germany", "Spain"};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_zzz);

    final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.activity_zzz, COUNTRIES);
    final AutoCompleteTextView textView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.myACTV);
    textView.setAdapter(adapter);
    closeKeyboard(this);
}


public void closeKeyboard(final Activity activity)
{
    final View view = activity.getCurrentFocus();

    if (view != null)
    {
        final InputMethodManager manager = (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        manager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
    }
}
```

}

activity.getCurrentFocus() returned null.

Comment: Can you try this to fetch the window token. Ideally as long a view is attached to a window, it should have a valid window token - `getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken()`

Comment: You may create a new view in this case, see my update.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly the focus may be on your button instead of AutoCompleteTextView.

You can use this method to close keyboard:

```
public void closeKeyboard(final Context context) {
    View view = context.getCurrentFocus();

    if (view == null) {
        view = new View(context);
    }

    final InputMethodManager manager = (InputMethodManager)
        context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

    manager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(
        view.getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS
    );
}
```

Code with my suggestions:

```
public class CountriesActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.countries);

        final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, COUNTRIES);

        final AutoCompleteTextView textView = (AutoCompleteTextView)
             findViewById(R.id.countries_list);

        textView.setAdapter(adapter);

        YourUiUtil.closeKeyboard(this);
    }

    private static final String[] COUNTRIES = new String[] {
        "Belgium", "France", "Italy", "Germany", "Spain"
    };
}
```

More details can be found [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html).

Comment: what does "android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line" refer to?

Comment: activity.getCurrentFocus(); returns null

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
public static void hideKeyboard(Context context) {
        if(((Activity) context).getCurrentFocus()!=null){
            View view = ((Activity) context).getCurrentFocus();
            if (view != null) {
                InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) context
                        .getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(),
                        InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
            }
        }else {
            InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(new View(context).getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
        }
    }
```

Please refer this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/19083268/4741746